# Assets in Super Table not working

Tags: assets, plugin-supertable

I have a assets field in a Super Table.
But the output from the image i selected in the Entry is just garbage:

```
O:28:"craft\elements\db\AssetQuery":82:{s:8:"volumeId";N;s:8:"folderId";N;s:8:"filename";N;s:4:"kind";N;s:5:"width";N;s:6:"height";N;s:4:"size";N;s:12:"dateModified";N;s:17:"includeSubfolders";b:0;s:14:"withTransforms";N;s:11:"elementType";s:20:"craft\elements\Asset";s:5:"query";N;s:8:"subQuery";N;s:12:"contentTable";s:12:"{{%content}}";s:12:"customFields";N;s:9:"inReverse";b:0;s:7:"asArray";b:0;s:6:"drafts";b:0;s:7:"draftId";N;s:7:"draftOf";N;s:12:"draftCreator";N;s:9:"revisions";b:0;s:10:"revisionId";N;s:10:"revisionOf";N;s:15:"revisionCreator";N;s:2:"id";N;s:3:"uid";N;s:10:"fixedOrder";b:0;s:6:"status";a:1:{i:0;s:7:"enabled";}s:8:"archived";b:0;s:7:"trashed";b:0;s:11:"dateCreated";N;s:11:"dateUpdated";N;s:6:"siteId";s:1:"*";s:6:"unique";b:1;s:11:"preferSites";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:14:"enabledForSite";b:1;s:6:"leaves";b:0;s:9:"relatedTo";N;s:5:"title";N;s:4:"slug";N;s:3:"uri";N;s:6:"search";N;s:3:"ref";N;s:4:"with";N;s:7:"orderBy";a:1:{s:19:"relations.sortOrder";i:4;}s:13:"withStructure";N;s:11:"structureId";N;s:5:"level";N;s:14:"hasDescendants";N;s:10:"ancestorOf";N;s:12:"ancestorDist";N;s:12:"descendantOf";N;s:14:"descendantDist";N;s:9:"siblingOf";N;s:13:"prevSiblingOf";N;s:13:"nextSiblingOf";N;s:16:"positionedBefore";N;s:15:"positionedAfter";N;s:17:"*defaultOrderBy";a:1:{s:20:"elements.dateCreated";i:3;}s:39:"craft\elements\db\ElementQuery_result";N;s:47:"craft\elements\db\ElementQuery_resultCriteria";N;s:45:"craft\elements\db\ElementQuery_searchScores";N;s:6:"select";a:1:{s:2:"**";s:2:"**";}s:12:"selectOption";N;s:8:"distinct";N;s:4:"from";N;s:7:"groupBy";N;s:4:"join";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;s:10:"INNER JOIN";i:1;s:24:"{{%relations}} relations";i:2;a:4:{i:0;s:3:"and";i:1;s:40:"[[relations.targetId]] = [[elements.id]]";i:2;a:2:{s:18:"relations.sourceId";s:3:"553";s:17:"relations.fieldId";s:2:"13";}i:3;a:3:{i:0;s:2:"or";i:1;a:1:{s:22:"relations.sourceSiteId";N;}i:2;a:1:{s:22:"relations.sourceSiteId";s:1:"1";}}}}}s:6:"having";N;s:5:"union";N;s:6:"params";a:0:{}s:18:"queryCacheDuration";N;s:20:"queryCacheDependency";N;s:27:"yii\base\Component_events";a:0:{}s:35:"yii\base\Component_eventWildcards";a:0:{}s:30:"yii\base\Component_behaviors";a:1:{s:12:"customFields";O:36:"craft\behaviors\ElementQueryBehavior":15:{s:8:"mainText";N;s:12:"previewImage";N;s:10:"textImages";N;s:5:"test1";N;s:8:"textBild";N;s:13:"textBildWidth";N;s:14:"textBildHeight";N;s:9:"textImage";N;s:14:"textImageWitdh";N;s:10:"categories";N;s:9:"entryType";N;s:10:"shortTitle";N;s:11:"previewText";N;s:51:"craft\behaviors\ContentBehavior_customFieldValues";a:0:{}s:5:"owner";r:1;}}s:5:"where";N;s:5:"limit";s:1:"1";s:6:"offset";N;s:7:"indexBy";N;s:16:"emulateExecution";b:0;}
666
```

A number field for example (the 666 at the end i have in textImageWitdh) works.
The code is just:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog').level(1) %}

  <h2 class="under">{{ entry.title }}</h2>
  {{ entry.getLink() }}
  {{ entry.previewText |raw }}
  {% for row in entry.textImages.all() %}
    {{ row.textImage }}
    <br />
    {{ row.textImageWitdh }}
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

The entry:
[image]
The Super Table:
[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your supertable setup? Your code doesn't show an image?

Comment: If i can find out how to make a screenshot. Since years I'm using Pearl Crescent Page Saver in Firefox. But in the Craft admin panel it captures only whats visible and not the whole site..

Comment: @user3788089, screenshot is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ok, two issues;

1. the image field is an array so you need to just select the first
2. you need an 'img' html tag as the twig code will only output the url

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog').level(1) %}

  <h2 class="under">{{ entry.title }}</h2>
  {{ entry.getLink() }}
  {{ entry.previewText |raw }}
  {% for row in entry.textImages.all() %}
    <img src="{{ row.textImage.one().url() }}">
    <br />
    {{ row.textImageWitdh }}
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```